# Getting warnings while "make test" PHP on Mac OS X (MySQL PDO->prepare())

Tags: php, mac-osx, php-fpm

Here are the results of "make test":

```
=====================================================================
TEST RESULT SUMMARY
---------------------------------------------------------------------
Exts skipped    :   46
Exts tested     :   33
---------------------------------------------------------------------

Number of tests : 13061              9219
Tests skipped   : 3842 ( 29.4%) --------
Tests warned    :    1 (  0.0%) (  0.0%)
Tests failed    :    7 (  0.1%) (  0.1%)
Expected fail   :   38 (  0.3%) (  0.4%)
Tests passed    : 9173 ( 70.2%) ( 99.5%)
---------------------------------------------------------------------
Time taken      : 1029 seconds
=====================================================================

=====================================================================
EXPECTED FAILED TEST SUMMARY
---------------------------------------------------------------------
Test script to verify that magic methods should be called only once when accessing an unset property. [tests/classes/bug63462.phpt]  XFAIL REASON: Bug 63462 is not yet fixed
Test open_basedir configuration [tests/security/open_basedir_linkinfo.phpt]  XFAIL REASON:     BUG: open_basedir cannot delete symlink to prohibited file. See also
bugs 48111 and 52176.
Inconsistencies when accessing protected members [Zend/tests/access_modifiers_008.phpt]  XFAIL     REASON: Discussion: http://marc.info/?l=php-internals&m=120221184420957&w=2
Inconsistencies when accessing protected members - 2 [Zend/tests/access_modifiers_009.phpt]  XFAIL REASON: Discussion: http://marc.info/?l=php-internals&m=120221184420957&w=2
Bug #48770 (call_user_func_array() fails to call parent from inheriting class) [Zend/tests/bug48770.phpt]  XFAIL REASON: See Bug #48770
Bug #48770 (call_user_func_array() fails to call parent from inheriting class) [Zend/tests/bug48770_2.phpt]  XFAIL REASON: See Bug #48770
Bug #48770 (call_user_func_array() fails to call parent from inheriting class) [Zend/tests/bug48770_3.phpt]  XFAIL REASON: See Bug #48770
Bug #63336 (invalid E_NOTICE error occur) [Zend/tests/bug63336.phpt]  XFAIL REASON: Bug is not fixed yet
Bug #64896 (Segfault with gc_collect_cycles using unserialize on certain objects) [Zend/tests/bug64896.phpt]  XFAIL REASON: We can not fix this bug without a significant (performace slow down) change to gc
Fixed Bug #65784 (Segfault with finally) [Zend/tests/bug65784.phpt]  XFAIL REASON: This bug is not fixed in 5.5 due to ABI BC
Initial value of static var in method depends on the include time of the class definition [Zend/tests/method_static_var.phpt]  XFAIL REASON: Maybe not a bug
DateTime::add() -- fall type2 type3 [ext/date/tests/DateTime_add-fall-type2-type3.phpt]  XFAIL REASON: Various bugs exist
DateTime::add() -- fall type3 type2 [ext/date/tests/DateTime_add-fall-type3-type2.phpt]  XFAIL     REASON: Various bugs exist
DateTime::add() -- fall type3 type3 [ext/date/tests/DateTime_add-fall-type3-type3.phpt]  XFAIL REASON: Various bugs exist
DateTime::add() -- spring type2 type3 [ext/date/tests/DateTime_add-spring-type2-type3.phpt]  XFAIL REASON: Various bugs exist
DateTime::add() -- spring type3 type2 [ext/date/tests/DateTime_add-spring-type3-type2.phpt]  XFAIL REASON: Various bugs exist
DateTime::add() -- spring type3 type3 [ext/date/tests/DateTime_add-spring-type3-type3.phpt]  XFAIL REASON: Various bugs exist
DateTime::diff() -- fall type2 type3 [ext/date/tests/DateTime_diff-fall-type2-type3.phpt]  XFAIL REASON: Various bugs exist
DateTime::diff() -- fall type3 type2 [ext/date/tests/DateTime_diff-fall-type3-type2.phpt]  XFAIL REASON: Various bugs exist
DateTime::diff() -- fall type3 type3 [ext/date/tests/DateTime_diff-fall-type3-type3.phpt]  XFAIL REASON: Various bugs exist
DateTime::diff() -- spring type2 type3 [ext/date/tests/DateTime_diff-spring-type2-type3.phpt]  XFAIL REASON: Various bugs exist
DateTime::diff() -- spring type3 type2 [ext/date/tests/DateTime_diff-spring-type3-type2.phpt]  XFAIL REASON: Various bugs exist
DateTime::diff() -- spring type3 type3 [ext/date/tests/DateTime_diff-spring-type3-type3.phpt]  XFAIL REASON: Various bugs exist
DateTime::sub() -- fall type2 type3 [ext/date/tests/DateTime_sub-fall-type2-type3.phpt]  XFAIL REASON: Various bugs exist
DateTime::sub() -- fall type3 type2 [ext/date/tests/DateTime_sub-fall-type3-type2.phpt]  XFAIL REASON: Various bugs exist
DateTime::sub() -- fall type3 type3 [ext/date/tests/DateTime_sub-fall-type3-type3.phpt]  XFAIL REASON: Various bugs exist
DateTime::sub() -- spring type2 type3 [ext/date/tests/DateTime_sub-spring-type2-type3.phpt]  XFAIL REASON: Various bugs exist
DateTime::sub() -- spring type3 type2 [ext/date/tests/DateTime_sub-spring-type3-type2.phpt]  XFAIL REASON: Various bugs exist
DateTime::sub() -- spring type3 type3 [ext/date/tests/DateTime_sub-spring-type3-type3.phpt]  XFAIL REASON: Various bugs exist
RFC: DateTime and Daylight Saving Time Transitions (zone type 3, bd2) [ext/date/tests/rfc-datetime_and_daylight_saving_time-type3-bd2.phpt]  XFAIL REASON: Still not quite right
RFC: DateTime and Daylight Saving Time Transitions (zone type 3, fs) [ext/date/tests/rfc-datetime_and_daylight_saving_time-type3-fs.phpt]  XFAIL REASON: Still not quite right
Bug #42718 (unsafe_raw filter not applied when configured as default filter) [ext/filter/tests/bug42718.phpt]  XFAIL REASON: FILTER_UNSAFE_RAW not applied when configured as default filter, even with flags
Bug #39858 (Lost connection to MySQL server during query by a repeated call stored proced) [ext/pdo_mysql/tests/bug_39858.phpt]  XFAIL REASON: nextRowset() problem with stored proc & emulation mode & mysqlnd
PDO MySQL Bug #41997 (stored procedure call returning single rowset blocks future queries) [ext/pdo_mysql/tests/bug_41997.phpt]  XFAIL REASON: nextRowset() problem with stored proc & emulation mode & mysqlnd
PECL Bug #7976 (Calling stored procedure several times) [ext/pdo_mysql/tests/bug_pecl_7976.phpt]  XFAIL REASON: Works with mysqlnd. It is not supported by libmysql. For libmysql is good enough to see no crash.
MySQL PDOStatement->nextRowSet() [ext/pdo_mysql/tests/pdo_mysql_stmt_nextrowset.phpt]  XFAIL REASON: nextRowset() problem with stored proc & emulation mode & mysqlnd
MySQL Prepared Statements and different column counts [ext/pdo_mysql/tests/pdo_mysql_stmt_variable_columncount.phpt]  XFAIL REASON: nextRowset() problem with stored proc & emulation mode & mysqlnd
Bug #45712 (NaN/INF comparison) [ext/standard/tests/math/bug45712.phpt]  XFAIL REASON: Bug 45712 not fixed yet.
=====================================================================

=====================================================================
FAILED TEST SUMMARY
---------------------------------------------------------------------
MySQL PDO->exec(), affected rows [ext/pdo_mysql/tests/pdo_mysql_exec.phpt]
MySQL: PDOStatement->getColumnMeta() [ext/pdo_mysql/tests/pdo_mysql_stmt_getcolumnmeta.phpt]
Phar front controller $_SERVER munging success [cache_list] [ext/phar/tests/cache_list/frontcontroller21.phpt]
Phar front controller $_SERVER munging success [ext/phar/tests/frontcontroller21.phpt]
Phar front controller $_SERVER munging success tar-based [ext/phar/tests/tar/frontcontroller21.phar.phpt]
Phar front controller $_SERVER munging success zip-based [ext/phar/tests/zip/frontcontroller21.phar.phpt]
Bug #52944 (segfault with zlib filter and corrupted data) [ext/zlib/tests/bug_52944-darwin.phpt]
=====================================================================

=====================================================================
WARNED TEST SUMMARY
---------------------------------------------------------------------
MySQL PDO->prepare(), emulated PS [ext/pdo_mysql/tests/pdo_mysql_prepare_emulated.phpt] (warn: XFAIL section but test passes)
=====================================================================

You may have found a problem in PHP.
This report can be automatically sent to the PHP QA team at
http://qa.php.net/reports and http://news.php.net/php.qa.reports
This gives us a better understanding of PHP's behavior.
If you don't want to send the report immediately you can choose
option "s" to save it.  You can then email it to qa-reports@lists.php.net later.
Do you want to send this report now? [Yns]: y

Please enter your email address.
(Your address will be mangled so that it will not go out on any
mailinglist in plain text): jnbdzjnbdz@gmail.com
error: /Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/usr/bin/libtool: unknown option character `-' in: --version
Usage: /Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/usr/bin/libtool -static [-] file [...] [-filelist listfile[,dirname]] [-arch_only arch] [-sacLT]
Usage: /Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/usr/bin/libtool -dynamic [-] file [...] [-filelist listfile[,dirname]] [-arch_only arch] [-o output] [-install_name name] [-compatibility_version #] [-current_version #] [-seg1addr 0x#] [-segs_read_only_addr 0x#] [-segs_read_write_addr 0x#] [-seg_addr_table <filename>] [-seg_addr_table_filename <file_system_path>] [-all_load] [-noall_load]

Posting to http://qa.php.net/buildtest-process.php

Thank you for helping to make PHP better.
```

Here are the commands I used:

```
./configure --enable-fpm --with-pdo-mysql --with-mcrypt --with-zlib --with-openssl --with-curl

make

make test
```

All in root.

I am on a Mac OS X 10.9.3 trying to install PHP-5.5.13.

Will these warnings cause my PHP code not to work? How do I solve this? While compiling I do get allot of warnings. Not sure where they are coming from.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The warning states the test was expected to fail but did not. Most of the time this is because the developer forgot to remove the "XFAIL" definition for the test after the bug was fixed.

There is no problem with PHP.

Comment: So I should be good to go?

Comment: Yes. Obviously make sure it works with your chosen front-end, but it'll work just fine.

Comment: Weird thing is when I use the browser it still gives me the old built I did yesterday but when I do php -v it shows me the built of today. I don't understand... Because of that I am missing extensions. Any ideas?

Comment: Be sure to restart everything (Apache, php-fpm, etc) as needed to get the new versions.

Comment: I had php-fpm stopped. I just start it and did not get any errors. Let me try to restart NGiNX.

Comment: Did not change anything. Maybe it created a second PHP setup... But it wouldn't make any sense.

Comment: This is a different issue that would likely warrant a question at our [SuperUser](http://superuser.com) site.

Comment: I just did: http://superuser.com/questions/769524/there-seems-to-be-multiple-php-running-on-my-mac-os-x

By the way thank you for your help.